# perl LibXML : validate doc against dtd, return boolean

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I'm trying to write a perl script using LibXML that validates a doc against a dtd and returns a boolean as to whether or not the doc is valid. I want to be able to run the script over a folder of xml files, report which are valid, which are not, and log the errors for those that are invalid.

The script I have does validate a doc, but it stops at the first invalid doc.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';
use XML::LibXML;
use IO::Handle;

# script to test dtd validity against test xml instance
my $instance = 'C:\jason\code\perl\dev\well-formed-test\family-instance1.xml';
$instance =~ s#\\#/#g;

print "about to test $instance \nagainst dtd\n\n";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->validation(1);
print "here we go...\n";
print "test : ", &isValid( $instance );
print "after sub.\n";



sub isValid {
   my $file = shift;
   return $parser->parse_file($instance);
}
```

I tried many variations on the script below, not using that sub, putting the parse command in an eval block, etc.

I had problems using filehandle->fd_open as per [this tutorial.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/perlxml/chapter/ch03.html). It also wasn't clear to me what the parse_file function returns as per the [cpan docs.](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0116/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod)

What's the best way to return a boolean val as to whether the doc is valid or not?

here's the xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE family SYSTEM "family.dtd">
<family>
    <member gender="female">
    <firstName>Sally</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
</member>
<member gender="male">
    <firstName>Bernie</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
</member>
<member gender="female">
    <firstName>Anna</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith-Jones</lastName>

</member>
</family>
```

and the dtd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT family (member+)>
<!ELEMENT member (firstName, lastName)>
<!ATTLIST member gender (male|female) 'male'>

<!ELEMENT firstName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastName (#PCDATA)>
```

the script runs as expected (it gets to that line 'after sub') if the file is valid, but when I add a tag that causes a failure

```
<sometag/>
```

the script prints out the error, but does not make it to that last line.
thanks!

Comment: `sub isValid { my $file = shift; return eval { $parser->parse_file($file); 1 }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML::LibXML` won't validate parsed documents against the DTD unless the [`validation`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#validation) parser option is set:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new(
    validation => 1,
);
```

This will throw an exception if an invalid document is parsed. Wrap the call to `parse_file` in an `eval` block to catch the exception.

```
my $doc = eval { $parser->parse_file($filename) };
if ( ! $doc ) {
    print("Can't parse $filename: $@");
}
```

Alternatively, you can parse a document without validation and use the [`is_valid`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#is_valid) method to validate afterwards:

```
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('filename.xml');
if ( ! $doc->is_valid ) {
    # Document does not validate...
}
```

In this case, `parse_file` might still throw an exception in case of other errors (file not found, document not well-formed). It depends on your use case which behavior is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#DOM_Parser) says:

```
All of the functions listed below will throw an exception if the document is invalid.
To prevent this causing your program exiting, wrap the call in an eval{} block
```

and [parse_file](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#parse_file) is one of those functions.

With [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), you can check for the result by expecting `S@` or `S!`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use File::Find to process multiple files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use XML::Parser; 

my $parser = XML::Parser->new();
find({
        wanted => \&wanted,
        no_chdir => 1,
        follow_fast => 1,
    },
    $ARGV[0],
);


sub wanted {
    return unless -f and m/\.xml$/i;
    eval {
        $parser->parsefile($File::Find::name);
    }; if( $@ ){
        printf STDERR "Not a valid XML document: %s\n", $File::Find::name;
    } else {
        printf STDERR "A valid XML document: %s\n", $File::Find::name;
    }
}
```